# Parse javamail message in android to get bodypart

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am trying to retrieve email using IMAP in android. I have managed to retrieve the messages from inbox folder, but facing difficulty in parsing them, particularly getting the body part of the message (that I intend to use further in my app).

All I need is a function that takes a message and returns me the plaintext body part (disregarding attachments if possible).

```
private String getbody(Message message) {           

    try {
        Object m=message.getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "abc";                // THE BODY PART TO RETURN
```

}

I have imported activation.jar file. However using `message.getcontent()`; is giving me error:

```
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getDataHandler(IMAPMessage.java:651)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1420)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at com.example.jmail.MainActivity$NetworkOperation.getbody(MainActivity.java:108)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at com.example.jmail.MainActivity$NetworkOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:87)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at com.example.jmail.MainActivity$NetworkOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-20 15:22:50.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main question is answered in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody).

The error you're getting has nothing to do with that.  Unfortunately, Android isn't Java, so it doesn't include javax.activation.  You'll need to figure out how to get that into Android.  You'll probably find the answer elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.. finally figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the help.. finally figured it out :)

The big mistake I had been doing for long was to add javamail and javabeans activation framework libraries for JRE to my build path.

There are separate library versions of javamail.jar and activation.jar (and one additional.jar) exclusively developed for Android that one may find [here.](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list)

Comment: Thnx man for sharing it, i was searching for solution to this issue for 3 hrs.JavaMail API or the android guys should mention this in their official documentation.